# Mathematically equivalent physical systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question

This seems a bit different than the typical question here, but I'm not sure where to ask. Is there a name or field of studying mathematically equivalent systems?

The simplest example I can think of is a particle in uniform circular motion parameterized by angle $\theta$. If we make the choice of having an identity $\theta \sim \theta + 2 \pi$ rather than restricting $\theta$, we get the same motion in $\theta$ as linear motion of a particle parameterized by $x$ despite the physical situations being different. However, I do fear that this may not be a real example because the identity condition essentially turns the angle into a line.

That was the only firm example I could think of, but the more original thing I was thinking of is when the Euler-Lagrange equations result in the same form as Newton's second law, but for a different coordinate (say $\ddot{\theta} = 0$ vs $\ddot{x} = 0$).

I feel like there should be other examples of this. Are there any notable ones? Is there a term describing different physical systems that are described by the same equations of motion without going back to a general equation of motion?

Comment: Reminds me of representation theory. Two systems are equivalent if they are two different representations of the same symmetries/equations of motion.

Comment: Canonicalization is a word that comes to mind. So you could calculate a 2D curve in rectangular or polar coordinates. It would be the same curve.

Comment: [system equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_equivalence) , [system analogy](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~sullivan/22files/System_analogy_all.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Any more complete answers are welcome, but I now have a direction to look in for the moment!

Comment: You are describing the idea of an analog computer.  An analog computer is a physical system constructed so that its behavior is described by equations of the same form as the equations you want to solve, or so that its behavior is described by the same as another system you want to model.  A wind tunnel with a reduced-scale model of an aircraft, for example, is an analog computer of sorts, providing results that can be interpreted to infer the performance of the real aircraft.  An electronic circuit can model a chemical reaction, if the equations for circuit and reaction have the same form.